# How to list ALL number from one to another using Python. This includes negative numbers

Tags: python-3.7

I want to list all numbers from one to another but I have no idea how. For example, I want the input to be something like 2 and -3 and for the output to be 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3.
    for i in reversed(range(b, a+1)):
        print(i)
        i = i-1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the integer numbers, you can do something like this:

```
a = int(input('first number: '))
b = int(input('second number: '))

if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
for i in range(a, b+1):
    print(i)
```